# Setting separate function parameters in JavaScript with addEventListener to have unique ids

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have a for loop that generates elements into a div, and I want to have each element calling the same function but with an unique id.

```
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    var p = document.createElement("p");
    
    var t = document.createTextNode("asdf");
    p.appendChild(t);
    
    p.addEventListener("click", function(e){popup(e, i);}, false);
    
    document.getElementById("someDiv").appendChild(p);
}
```

let's say, the function is:

```
function popup(e, id)
{
    //do stuff with the mouse event and get data according to the id
}
```

so I need the `mouse` event object.

This current code does make the elements, but every click calls the function with the same id as parameter (10 is being sent as the id, the `mouse` event works fine).

Any idea is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's happening because a closure is created that retains the last value of `i` from the for loop, you need to change this line:

```
p.addEventListener("click", function(e){popup(e, i);}, false);
```

To fix this, first declare a new function:

```
function createfunc(i) {
    return function(e) {popup(e, i); }
}
```

Then change that line to:

```
p.addEventListener("click", createfunc(i), false);
```

Check [**this question**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/750486/439667) for more information about this technique.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I wish your first solution would have worked (before the edit), because it was much simpler, but I'm glad that this one does the job. :)
PS.: thanks for the more info link. It's really helpful!

Comment: @Isti115 You are welcome, I am not sure my first answer would have worked though.